# Set a Cookie on WOAHbar jQuery to Remember Previous State

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using the WOAHbar that is a free alternative to the Hello Bar. I got it here:

http://blog.jobdeals.com/2011/12/free-hellobar-com-alternative-source-code/

It's really awesome. The only thing I want it to do is remember the state the user chooses when that user visits another post or page. I know you can do this with cookies, I just don't know how. Here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stub_showing = false;

function woahbar_show() { 
    if(stub_showing) {
      $('.woahbar-stub').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
        $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
      }); 
    }
    else {
      $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
      $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
    }
}

function woahbar_hide() { 
    $('.woahbar').slideUp('fast', function() {
      $('.woahbar-stub').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100);  
      stub_showing = true;
    }); 

    if( $(window).width() > 1024 ) {
      $('body').animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, 250); // if width greater than 1024 pull up the body
    }
}

$().ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    woahbar_show();
 }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="woahbar" style="display:none">
    <span>
    Want access to the largest inventory of storage auctions online?  <a class="woahbar-link" href="http://storageunitauctionlist.com/register-signup.php" target="_blank">Sign Up Today!</a>
    </span>
    <a class="close-notify" onclick="woahbar_hide();"><img class="woahbar-up-arrow" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/woahbar-up-arrow.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="woahbar-stub" style="display:none">
    <a class="show-notify" onclick="woahbar_show();"><img class="woahbar-down-arrow" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/woahbar-down-arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

edit:

I tried adding cookies using the jQuery Cookie Plugin. I'm new to jQuery, so I'm not real sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stub_showing = false;
var state = 'updown';

function woahbar_show() { 
    if(stub_showing) {
      $('.woahbar-stub').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
        $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
      }); 
    }
    else {
      $('.woahbar').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100); 
      $('body').animate({"marginTop": "2.4em"}, 250);
    }
}

$.cookie('state', 'updown', { expires: 7 });

function woahbar_hide() { 
    $('.woahbar').slideUp('fast', function() {
      $('.woahbar-stub').show('bounce', { times:3, distance:15 }, 100);  
      stub_showing = true;
    }); 

    if( $(window).width() > 1024 ) {
      $('body').animate({"marginTop": "0px"}, 250); // if width greater than 1024 pull up the body
    }
}

$().ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    woahbar_show();
 }, 5000);


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com) and store the value of the `state` inside the cookie like:

at the top of your script declare the variable you want to use to store your cookie like:

```
var state; // declare the variable
```

later, somewhere in your code set the value after the user inputs the `state`

```
$.cookie('state', '{the input state value}', { expires: 7 });
```

Comment: I edited my question above with my attempt to add cookies. Like I said above, I'm new to jQuery and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.